# Alternate between uppercase and downcase

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to ask the user five times to enter a word, and spat the answers on each line alternating with uppercase and lowercase, without using the `each_with_index` method. I'm also trying to sort the answers alphabetically. Below is what I have done:

```
words = []

5.times do
  puts "Please enter a word:"
  words << gets.chomp
end

 words.each do |word|
   if words.even?
     puts words.downcase
   elsif words.odd?
     puts words.upcase
   end
 end
```

but everything I have tried has failed. How can I have the user input alternate between uppercase and downcase without the `each_with_index` method?

Answer (score 2):

```
words = %w| how now brown cow |

enum = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
words.map { |w| w.send enum.next }
  #=> ["HOW", "now", " BROWN", "cow"]
```

Comment: I was about to post the same `cycle` solution “in honor of @CarySwoveland.” I should've known I'd be too slow!

Answer (score 1):

```
words.each_slice(2) {|f,s| puts f.downcase; puts s.upcase if s }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just have one more question. How can I sort the final results in alphabetical order?

Comment: You must define empty array, then add in this array your values, then use `sort`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
words = []
sorted_words = []

5.times do
  puts "Please enter a word:"
  words << gets.chomp
end

words.sort!.each do |w|
  if words.index(w).even?
    sorted_words << w.downcase
  else
    sorted_words << w.upcase
  end
end
p sorted_words
```

Answer (score -1):

```
words = Array.new(5){puts "Please enter a word:"; gets.chomp}
words.inject(false){|up, word| puts word.send(up ? :upcase : :downcase); !up}
```