# Using Ruby, I want to ask user for a word 5x then sort the list and capitalize every other word

Tags: ruby

yes , this is a study question. I've been banging my head on a wall over this. what I have so far...

```
words = []
5.times do
  puts "Please enter a word:"
  words << gets.chomp.upcase
end

puts "Here are your words:" 
puts words.sort
```

start this video at 6:00
more info: https://vimeo.com/125941774

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I downcase every other word?

Comment: You have `capitalize` in the title, `upcase` in the code snippet and now you mention `downcase`. Please restate your question so that we could understand what do you need.

Comment: yes, in the snippet I used .upcase but should I use that to capitalize every other word in the array?

Comment: I want the output to display 5 words, sorted alphabetically and every other word capitalized.

Comment: While I agree that the question needs editing, the downvotes are only deserved for failing to post a corpus and desired output, not for the question itself which is actually pretty reasonable. People should not be downvoting because the question seems basic, or because it's homework. In addition, there is a useful question here, and I disagree with the close votes.

Comment: @vmarqs: `words.map(&:downcase)`

Comment: vmarqs, when you are asked for clarification you need to edit the question, not respond in comments (which some readers may miss).

Comment: You may wish to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443273/alternate-between-uppercase-and-downcase/35443386#comment58589370_35443386). btw, do you mean I should start that video at 6:00am tomorrow? That's pretty early for me.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It’s CET :)

Answer (score 1):

```
words = []
5.times do
  puts "Please enter a word:"
  words << gets.chomp   # no .upcase here, upcase converts all letters
end

result = words.sort.map.with_index do |w, i| 
           w[0] = w[0].upcase if i.odd?
         end
puts "Here are your words:" 
puts result
```

Answer (score 0):

### Capitalizing and Uppercasing Are Not Synonyms

Capitalizing and uppercasing are two different things. Since your question asked about capitalizing (e.g. title-casing), you can construct your code around the following examples.

One example uses features from the latest MRI Ruby, while the other uses ActiveSupport from Rails. More complex solutions are possible by indexing into strings, but why do it the hard way?

#### Ruby 2.3.0+

Use the new [String#capitalize](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) method. For example:

```
words = %w[foo bar baz quux wibble]
words.each_with_index.map { |word, idx| idx.even? ? word.capitalize : word }
#=> ["Foo", "bar", "Baz", "quux", "Wibble"]
```

This will capitalize ever other word in the list. Use [Integer#odd?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F) instead of [Integer#even?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F) to check the *idx* variable if you prefer.

#### Use Rails Extensions

If you have an older Ruby, you can use methods from [the facets gem](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets) or [the "inflections" string extension from Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#inflections) to do the same thing. For example, with ActiveSupport:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'

words = %w[foo bar baz quux wibble]
words.each_with_index.map { |word, idx| idx.even? ? word.titlecase : word }
#=> ["Foo", "bar", "Baz", "quux", "Wibble"]
```

Comment: There was a request to sort elements in OP.

Comment: @mudasobwa So? This isn't a homework writing service. The OP clearly already knows how to #sort an array; that wasn't the real problem. I chose to address the X in this X/Y problem, but you are certainly free to post alternative answers.

Comment: what if it is upcasing every other word?

Comment: @vmarqs Then call #upcase instead of #capitalize. In future, make sure your questions include **your desired output** if you want to avoid downvotes.